# Using Big Query SQL I can I achieve the following subtraction ( subtract two row values and replace it with that value )?

Tags: sql, replace, google-bigquery, subtraction

| application | buildingid | dashboarding_tag | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abacus | BLD01 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 3000.00 |
| Abacus | BLD02 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 1000.00 |
| Abacus | BLD04 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 1000.00 |
| Abacus | BLD05 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 500.00 |
| Abacus | BLD02 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 300.00 |
| Abacus | BLD03 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 900.00 |
| Abacus | BLD04 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 50.00 |
| Abacus | BLD05 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 80.00 |
| Abacus | BLD06 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 200.00 |
| Forell | BLD07 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 0.00 |
| Forell | BLD08 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 50.00 |
| Forell | BLD09 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | -5.00 |
| Forell | BLD10 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | -30.00 |

to

| application | buildingid | dashboarding_tag | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abacus | BLD01 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 3000.00 |
| Abacus | BLD02 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 700.00 |
| Abacus | BLD04 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 950.00 |
| Abacus | BLD05 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 420.00 |
| Abacus | BLD02 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 300.00 |
| Abacus | BLD03 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 900.00 |
| Abacus | BLD04 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 50.00 |
| Abacus | BLD05 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 80.00 |
| Abacus | BLD06 | MVHR_Energy_Consumption | 200.00 |
| Forell | BLD07 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 0.00 |
| Forell | BLD08 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | 50.00 |
| Forell | BLD09 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | -5.00 |
| Forell | BLD10 | Heating_System_Energy_Consumption | -30.00 |

Notice how the values in row 2 ,3 and 4 changed on table 2 based on values in row 5,7,8.

The logic is , if the application is Abacus , then always replace the value of the Heating_System_Energy_Consumption such that:

Heating_System_Energy_Consumption=Heating_System_Energy_Consumption-MVHR_Energy_Consumption
for each building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(value), 
  if(dashboarding_tag = 'Heating_System_Energy_Consumption', 
    value - sum(if(dashboarding_tag = 'MVHR_Energy_Consumption', value, 0)) over(partition by application, buildingid), 
  value) as value
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly , just wanted to add a little edit specific to my table in case someone else wants to refer to this :                                                                                                    
 select * except(value), 
  if(dashboarding_tag = 'Heating_System_Energy_Consumption' AND `application`='Abacus', 
    value - sum(if(dashboarding_tag = 'MVHR_Energy_Consumption', value, 0)) over(partition by application, buildingid), 
  value) as value
from your_table